# Can you generate a package and group of classes through templates in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, templates, ide

All of my domain objects follow a very similar structure, if I wanted to store Address objects in my application, I would create in a .address package an Address, IAddressService, AddressServiceImpl, as well as an AddressServiceImplTest in a corresponding test package. All of these objects seem like they could be easily templated, however I usually find myself just copying a similar domain object and renaming classes manually.

Is there a template method in eclipse, or a plugin, that could autogenerate several classes and several packages in one shot for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a prebuilt solution.
However, you can consider writing your own, specialized template engine using 
[Java Emitter Templates](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html).